# SQL query not returning all possible rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing a simple `SQL` query to get the latest records for every customerid.
My `SQL` query -

```
SELECT sub.customerid, sub.device_count, sub.date_time FROM(
    SELECT customerid, cast(device_count as INT) as device_count, date_time,
        RANK() OVER
            (
                PARTITION by customerid
                ORDER BY date_time desc
            ) AS rownum 
    FROM tableA ) sub 
JOIN tableB d on sub.customerid = d.customerid 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Sample data:

| customerid | device_count | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3573 | 2021-07-26 02:15:09-05:00 |
| A | 4 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 16988 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 20696 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 24655 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 10000 | 2021-07-25 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 2000 | 2021-07-25 02:15:13-05:00 |

What I need is:

| customerid | device_count | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 16988 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 20696 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 24655 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |

But what I get after executing the above query is :

| customerid | device_count | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 16988 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |

I am not sure why the remaining rows are left out even though they have the same timestamp. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp might have milliseconds that you are are not seeing.

You can truncate to the nearest second:

```
SELECT sub.customerid, sub.device_count, sub.date_time
FROM (SELECT customerid, cast(device_count as INT) as device_count, date_time,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION by customerid ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC(second, date_time) desc) AS rownum 
      FROM tableA
     ) sub JOIN
     tableB d 
     ON sub.customerid = d.customerid 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your prompt response! Why wouldn't SQL give all the records with same timestamp?

Comment: @sagar_c_k . . . The timestamps only *look* like they are the same.  They are different in fractions of a second.